# Term for a quote's 'author' or 'creator'

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, vocabulary

I am looking for the correct term to describe a quote's author or creator.

For example, the quote is:

> If you are going to go through hell, keep going.

The quotee/quoter/author(?) is:

> Winston Churchill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While *author* is correct, it may convey images of more comprehensive works.

Perhaps **[source](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/source)**

> a person, group, etc, that creates, issues, or originates something

Answer (score -2):

I'd say [quotee](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quotee).

> Or it can summarize the inner thoughts of either the quoter or the quotee (“She’s like, yeah, as if I’d be caught dead in them! And I’m like, I care what you think?”). —
>   [2007 July 15, Patricia T. O’Conner, “Like”, New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2007/07/15/magazine/15wwln-guest-t.html)

Author can work too. Quoter is definitely wrong.